# Is there any success or failure response from corda?

Tags: corda

like this..
Informational responses (100–199),
Successful responses (200–299),
Redirects (300–399),
Client errors (400–499),
and Server errors (500–599).

If it is not there how we can get it manualy?

Comment: Corda provides RPC call, instead of RESTful API call, so not such kind of HTTP codes are provided. It is Web server developers' scope for the HTTP code.

Answer (score 0):

Corda only provides RPC interface instead of RESTful API, so not such kind of HTTP codes are provided. It is Web server developers' scope to design web server logic and then decide the HTTP code.